# custom layout did not fit in Dialog window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed the following custom layout to be inflated into a DialogFragment then
I added the positive & negative buttons programatically

but the last TextView in the layout has not shown up into the Dialog window and was covered by the negative and positive

How can I overcome this problem?

Here is the code of my Dialog custom layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/result"
        tools:context=".ResultActivity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResult"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Result Value" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Result Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Advice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAdviceMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Advice Message"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to use a ScrollView. This is how

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewResult"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/result"
                tools:context=".ResultActivity" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResult"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Result Value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResultPercent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Result Message" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewResultMsg"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/Advice" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewAdviceMsg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewAdvice"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Advice Message"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it all inside a scroll view.